# Junit Before/After and setup/teardown

Tags: java, testing, junit

Are the `setUp` and `teardown` (precondition and postcondition settings) identified by the name `setUp()` and `teardown()` or by `@Before` and `@After`?

In other words is it possible in JUnit to have a `@Before teardown()` and a `@After setUp()`?

Comment: If only there was a way to test that... Or some documentation...

Comment: I'm sorry for have bothered you. I'm just studying and I don't have a fast way to test it and I was looking a faster way to answer this easy question than looking in a huge documentation.

Comment: It would have been faster to write a test with a setup method annotated with @After than to write your question. That's a lame excuse. A huge part of the job is to read documentation, write code and try things. If you're studying, that's what you should learn to do.

Comment: if I said i don't have a fast way to test it means I can't write a setup method annotated with @After. This is a question about a techical issue, not a question about how to study. Thank you very much for your off topic comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JUnit 3: the methods are identified by name `setUp` and `tearDown`

JUnit 4: the methods are identified by annotation `@Before` and `@After`

JUnit 5: the methods are identified by annotation `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach`

*edit:* To answer your question, yes it is possible to write

```
@Before
public void tearDown() {...}
```

but this would not increase the readability of your code.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. But, still I guess author was just confused whether it's possible to mix them. And the answer here is NO.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the version of JUnit that you use. In case you have annotations, it's most probably JUnit 4. In such case it doesn't matter how you name your methods, what is more important is that which annotations you use. Usage of annotations helps in defining clear logic without "magic" with method names. If you use Junit 4, you can call methods whatever you want, you just need put corresponding annotations above them.